# Which version of software should I use ? (Stable or Last)

Tags: laravel, software-design, software-distribution

It is important to me to know whcih version of software should I use?
Last or Stable?
For example: 
Laravel 5.5 (Stable) or Laravel 5.6 (Last)
cPanel 68.0.19 (Stable) or cPanel 68.1.1 (Last)

Comment: Well the question is do you want to have a latest release with bug security venerability or stable and proven to be working.

Comment: Where are you getting this information from? 5.6 is not currently the latest version of Laravel, it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: You shouldn't use cPanel, ever, stable or otherwise. Laravel only releases "stable" versions, they don't have an unstable (although there are "Release Candidate" versions prior to a final release of new versions, and you could use the `master` branch).

Comment: @usrNotFound I want to make software with laravel I have two choice 1: use 5.5 stable release 2: wait for 5.6 or ... laravel 5.6 is example not released yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options with Laravel:

**Long Term Support**

For those not familiar with long-term support, these are special versions that are feature locked at the date of release. They do not get any new features but keep getting bug fixes and security updates throughout the maintenance window.

For LTS releases, such as **Laravel 5.5**, bug fixes are provided for 2 years and security fixes are provided for 3 years. These releases provide the longest window of support and maintenance. For general releases, bug fixes are provided for 6 months and security fixes are provided for 1 year.

Version 5.1 was Laravel’s first LTS release.

LTS versions are popular with companies looking to reduce the risk, expense, and disruption of software deployment, while promoting the dependability of the software. It does not imply technical support.

**Framework Releases**

Major framework releases are released every six months (February and August), while minor releases may be released as often as every week. Minor releases should never contain breaking changes.

Using the latest release of the framework provides access to not only the latest security updates, but also new features.  Updating your application to the latest release of the framework allows you to take advantage of new features and keeping migrations between subsequent versions relatively straightforward. It’s also an opportunity to refactor code to utilise the functionality of the framework. The work associated with upgrading is incremental, rather than the big jump between LTS versions.

If you follow the installation instructions (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5), you will be downloading the latest release of the framework.

Comment: thanks, but yest i can not decide which version i should use.

Comment: Tell us more about what the implementation is for. Small side project with one or two developers?  Internal app for medium size company?  Large public app with multiple development teams?  Is there budget and processes for ongoing support and maintenance?  What is your / your company’s appetite for risk?

Comment: I want to make free CMS and some paid plugins.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use the latest release of the framework.  Install via Composer or ph-storm and it will download this version for you.  Check out laracasts.com for getting started tutorials as well as the fantastic series 'Let's Build A Forum'.

Comment: Good recommendation but In this way I should wait for next 5.6 version and always I do migration to latest release.